# Trying to determine the meaning of "event.target.contains===this.node"

Tags: javascript, nodes

I'm working on some React stuff, and I found [this](https://codepen.io/devhamsters/pen/yMProm) relevant codepen to my work. Looking through their source code, they used some syntax I'm unfamiliar with.

Specifically, this line in the _handleClick function confused me:

```
const wasOutside = !(event.target.contains === this.root);
```

In the context of the code, it's checking to see whether or not the user has clicked outside of a context menu that was generated with a right click. I under stand *what* it's doing, but I'm unclear on *how* it's doing it. I've tried to track down documentation on event.target.contains, but I've had no luck.

Here's what I *think* is happening. Event.target gives me a node location. This.root is also a node location on the dom. I think that event.target.contains is the same as node.contains, but per my reading of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), I think that node.contains could only return a boolean true or false, and it would take an argument of some sort? So far as I can tell, there's no way for wasOutside to have any value except for true, and this code is unnecessary. Is this accurate? Am I missing something, or interpreting something incorrectly?

Comment: event.target.contains returns not even boolean, it returns function itself, so i dont see any sense in such code... It will never return true, no way

Comment: I also don't understand it. It should be `!event.target.contains(this.root)`

Comment: Good catch -- I didn't noticethat it wasn't an actual function call.

Comment: The comparison always fails, so it always sets `wasOutside` to `true`.

Comment: Just because you found it on the Internet, it doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I was wanting to confirm. Just because I think something is incorrect also doesn't mean that it is correct. It's nice to get a second opinion before I fall victim to the Dunning Kruger effect and dismiss something I'm unfamiliar with.